# Date Comparision in PHP and my sql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to compare database field of date that has YYYY-MM-DD

format and i want to compare from MM-DD

actually i want to fetch records those have birthdays between month /selected week durations

and birthdate is stores as YYYY-MM-DD format in db table

how can i achieve this kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your sql you could try something like the following:

```
select * from people where birthdate>='10/01/2010' AND birthdate<='30/01/2010';
```

if you want to get more specific with months and days then you can utilise the `month(birthdate)` and `day(birthdate)` functions in mysql;

```
select * from people where month(birthdate)=10;
```

would return all your people where the month for birthdate is October.

Comment: thanx for your reply,but want to fetch specific from specific week
 so i want to something like this

select * from table_name where birthdate is between week 33

Comment: select * from table_name where birthdate>=16-08 AND birthdate<=22-08

like this way

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

you can use CURDATE(), DATE_ADD() and DATE_SUB() to make date interval